# Converting comma, separated horizontal string to vertical

Tags: sql, oracle, split

Hi I know how to convert `a,b,c,d,e` into

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

I have written the below query for the same.

```
select substr(replace('a,b,c,d,e',',',null),level,1) 
from dual 
connect by level <=length(replace('a,b,c,d,e',',',null));
```

but I am not able to convert `aa,b,cc,d` 
 into

```
aa
b
cc
d
```

Is there anyway we can do the same when we don't know the length of characters

Comment: ```select REPLACE ( 'aa,b,cc,d',',', CHR(10) ) FROM DUAL;```

Comment: `with temp as
 (select  'aa,b,cc,d,2,3,hello,test' test
    from dual)
select 
       trim(regexp_substr(t.test, '[^,]+', 1, levels.column_value)) as TEST
  from temp t,
       table(cast(multiset
                  (select level
                     from dual
                   connect by level <=
                              length(regexp_replace(t.test, '[^,]+')) + 1) as
                  sys.OdciNumberList)) levels`

Comment: I need it is in Oracle